# Matching anonymous functions to the event behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript

When I do

```
<a onclick='foo()'></a>
```

According to firebug - it creates anonymous function

like this :

```
function onclick(event) { foo(); }
```

But **how does he knows** how to attach those both to each other ?

( maybe the click came from `DIV` and not from this `A` )

I'm missing this point...

Can I please  have some Explanation ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the `event` argument passed to the function contains the element as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `<a onclick="foo()"></a>`, you should be beaten with a dirty stick. Repeatedly.

Anyway, this line bind an anonymous function to the DOM node. Each DOM element has them. Inspect your page an you will see all the properties which each dom element has.

Instead of mixing you layers of web ( JS code has no place in HTML ) , you should attach the events from an external JS file, which you include right before `</body>`. In addition to making the page load faster on older browers, this will effectively place all the content of that file in `onDomReady` event.

Please read more about **how** to attach events here : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: *"When you do `<a onclick="foo()"></a>`, you should be beaten with a dirty stick."* I completely disagree. Every technique has its place, including this one. You seem to have an unbalanced view that looks only at what you perceive as cons, and ignores the pros (which are very real).

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ , i suspect that i am well aware of most of the cons for writing inline javascript in html.. Could you list some of the pros. It would be appropriated (or maybe we can take it to the [javascript chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) , if you like).

Comment: What I consider to be pros are wide browser compatibility, zero DOM-ready issues, zero time lag between between element availability and behavior availability (assuming any functions invoked were loaded in the head, or at least before the elements), no manual binding needed for client-side generated elements, and ease of implementation when the elements receiving the attribute are dynamically generated on the server. I'd agree that if there are lots and lots of these, it could be an issue, but then in that case, it's likely that event delegation is needed irrespective of the binding method. ;)

Comment: ...ah, also slightly simplified `event` object access. With `<a onclick='foo(event)'></a>`, the event object will be available in both IE and W3C compliant browsers. So no need for `e = e || window.event`, but that's a pretty small thing in my book.

Answer (score 1):

Each element has a set of default properties of methods. When an user changes a property/method, the browser is smart enough to remember this change.

Similarly, multiple functions with the same name can exist in JavaScript:

```
function a(){
   this.same_name = function(){
       return "a";
   } 
}
function b(){
   this.same_name = function(){
       return "b";
   }
}
```